# Как при помощи Navigation Drawer переключаться между разными экранами?

Tags: java, android

Суть проблемы заключается в следующем: есть главная активность, и при попытке переключения на другую, все компоненты другой активности просто накладываются на главную. Каким образом это можно исправить.
Прилагаю код:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private TextView mDateDisplayStart;
    private TextView mDateDisplayEnd;
    private ImageButton mPickDateStart;
    private ImageButton mPickDateEnd;
    private String[] mScreenTitles;
    private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
    private ListView mDrawerList;

    private android.support.v4.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;
    private CharSequence mDrawerTitle;
    private CharSequence mTitle;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mDateDisplayStart = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.dateStart);
        mDateDisplayEnd = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.dateEnd);
        mPickDateStart = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.showDateStartPicker);
        mPickDateEnd = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.showDateEndPicker);
        final Context context = this;
        mPickDateStart.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                MyDatePicker dlg = new MyDatePicker(context);
                dlg.setTextView(mDateDisplayStart);
                dlg.show();
            }
        });
        mPickDateEnd.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                MyDatePicker dlg = new MyDatePicker(context);
                dlg.setTextView(mDateDisplayEnd);
                dlg.show();
            }
        });
        mTitle = mDrawerTitle = getTitle();
        mScreenTitles = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.screen_array);
        mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        mDrawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.left_drawer);

        // Set the adapter for the list view
        mDrawerList.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                R.layout.drawer_list_item, mScreenTitles));
        // Set the list's click listener
        mDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new DrawerItemClickListener());

        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);

        mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, /* host Activity */
                mDrawerLayout, /* DrawerLayout object */
                R.drawable.ic_drawer, /* nav drawer icon to replace 'Up' caret */
                R.string.drawer_open, /* "open drawer" description */
                R.string.drawer_close /* "close drawer" description */
        ) {

            /** Called when a drawer has settled in a completely closed state. */
            public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
                getSupportActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
                supportInvalidateOptionsMenu(); // creates call to onPrepareOptionsMenu()
            }

            /** Called when a drawer has settled in a completely open state. */
            public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
                getSupportActionBar().setTitle(mDrawerTitle);
                supportInvalidateOptionsMenu(); // creates call to onPrepareOptionsMenu()
            }
        };

        // Set the drawer toggle as the DrawerListener
        mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);

        // Initialize the first fragment when the application first loads.
        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            selectItem(0);
        }
    }

    private void updateDisplay(TextView tv, Calendar c) {
        tv.setText(new StringBuilder()
                .append(c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH))
                .append("/")
                .append(c.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1)
                .append("/")
                .append(c.get(Calendar.YEAR)));
    }

    private class MyDatePicker extends DatePickerDialog {

        public MyDatePicker(Context context) {
            super(
                    context,
                    null,
                    Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.YEAR),
                    Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.MONTH),
                    Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
        }
        // Раскомментируй, если нужен такой конструктор
//      public MyDatePicker(Context context, @Nullable OnDateSetListener listener, int y, int m, int d) {
//          super(context, listener, y, m, d);
//      }

        private final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();

        private TextView tv = null;

        @Override
        public void onDateChanged(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int dayOfMonth) {
            // По мере изменения даты, обновляем Calendar:
            c.clear();
            c.set(year, month, dayOfMonth);

            // Если хочешь, чтобы дата менялась по мере ввода раскомментируй
            //if (tv!=null) updateDisplay(tv, c);
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            if (which == DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE && tv != null) {
                updateDisplay(tv, c);
            }
            super.onClick(dialog, which);
        }

        public void setTextView(TextView textView) {
            tv = textView;
        }
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu;
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // If the nav drawer is open, hide action items related to the content view
        boolean drawerOpen = mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(mDrawerList);
        menu.findItem(R.id.action_search).setVisible(!drawerOpen);
        return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Pass the event to ActionBarDrawerToggle, if it returns
        // true, then it has handled the app icon touch event
        if (mDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
            return true;
        }
        // Handle action buttons
        switch(item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.action_search:
                // Show toast about click.
                Toast.makeText(this, R.string.action_search, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return true;
            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }
    /* The click listener for ListView in the navigation drawer */
    private class DrawerItemClickListener implements ListView.OnItemClickListener {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            selectItem(position);
        }
    }
    /** Swaps fragments in the main content view */
    private void selectItem(int position) {
        // Update the main content by replacing fragments
        Fragment fragment = null;
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                fragment = new ScreenOne();
                break;
            case 1:
                fragment = new ScreenTwo();
                break;
            case 2:
                fragment = new ScreenThree();
                break;
            case 3:
                fragment = new ScreenFour();
            default:
                break;
        }

        // Insert the fragment by replacing any existing fragment
        if (fragment != null) {
            FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment).commit();

            // Highlight the selected item, update the title, and close the drawer
            mDrawerList.setItemChecked(position, true);
            setTitle(mScreenTitles[position]);
            mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);
        } else {
            // Error
            Log.e(this.getClass().getName(), "Error. Fragment is not created");
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void setTitle(CharSequence title) {
        mTitle = title;
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
    }

    /**
     * When using the ActionBarDrawerToggle, you must call it during
     * onPostCreate() and onConfigurationChanged()...
     */

    @Override
    protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // Sync the toggle state after onRestoreInstanceState has occurred.
        mDrawerToggle.syncState();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        // Pass any configuration change to the drawer toggles
        mDrawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    }

    public void Bronirovat(View view) {
        Intent nextActivity = new Intent(this, Bronirovat.class);
        startActivity(nextActivity);
    }
}
```

Comment: В какой роли у Вас выспупает Navigation Drawer при смене activity?

Comment: Как я понимаю, у вас не активити накладываются, а фрагменты? И изначальный фрагмент у вас прямо в разметке указан?

Comment: @KeyGenQT в роли бокового меню

Comment: @ЮрийСПб Да, изначальный фрагмент указан в разметке

Answer (score 1):

Скорее всего дело в том, что изначальный фрагмент добавлен в активити через разметку. Так не стоит делать. Добавьте его программно, удалив из разметки, как-то так:

```
Fragment initialFragment = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.container);
if (initialFragment == null)
{
    initialFragment = new FragmentInitial();
    getSupportFragmentManager().
            beginTransaction().add(R.id.container, initialFragment)
            .commit();
}
```